# How to retrieve data from one to one relationship in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have two MSSQL tables so i created two models [Adress] and [Webshop]. The foreign key is Adresse in both tables.

1.Model [Adress]

```
class Adress extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Adress";
    protected $primaryKey = 'Adresse';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function webshop()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Webshop', 'Adresse');
    }
}
```

2.Model [WebShop]

```
class Webshop extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Webshop";
    protected $primaryKey = 'Adresse';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function adress()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Adress','Adresse');
    }
}
```

I would like to make a table with some data from the first and second table like the webshopID, mobile is in  [Webshop] table and adress in the [Adress] table. I think this is a one to one relationship between this two tables.

in `php artisan tinker`:

```
App\Adress::all();          -> this is working 
App\Adress::find(2910)->webshop  -> this is also working
App\Adress::with('webshop')->get() -> this is NOT working
```

I would like to retrieve data from this two tables at the same time. Is this possible with a relationship or do i heave to use the joins?

EDIT:
maybe my foreignKeys are wrong

Adress table:
[image]

Webshop table:
[image]

Comment: both your models have `protected $primaryKey = 'Adresse';` ? Seems a little weird or is "Adresse" your default id column name? What is the exact error you get?

Comment: elaborate on tables schema

Comment: its a default id column name. A int as a primary key.  I don't get any error, i'm waitng about  2-3min and then appers nothing.

Comment: i edited my question and added pics from this two tables

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this -

```
use App\Adress;
use App\Webshop;

$result = Webshop::with('Adress')->where('Webshop.id',$id)->get();
or
$result = Adress::with('Webshop')->where('Adress.id',$id)->get();
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your relationship in `Address` model to

```
$this->hasOne('App\Webshop', 'Adresse', 'Adresse');
```

and in `Webshop` model

```
$this->belongsTo('App\Address', 'Adresse', 'Adresse');
```

**EDIT**

Now to retrieve the relationships you can do

```
$webshop = App\Address::find($id)->webshop;
$address = App\Webshop::find($id)->address
```

Comment: with the limit command `App\Adress::where('webshop)->limit(10)->get()` is working. when i use this command  `App\Adress::where('webshop)->get()` the tinkes freezes for 2-3min and does nothing no error no result just a new line where i can put my command in cmd

Comment: I think that you should read the Laravel documentation. You cannot make a `where` clause on a relationship, instead use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method. Check my andwer edit

Comment: Then you are defining One-to-One relationships. `App\Address::find($id)->webshop` will return only one element

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake not `where`... `with` !

Comment: no is not wokring i get an error: `BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`

Comment: i tried also `App\Adress::with('webshop')->get()` a here comes an error: `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43869 bytes)`

Comment: Oh, that's the problem, you have too many records in the DB so php does not have enough memory to allocate to retrieved results. Use `limit` to retrieve successfully your records.

Comment: So my solution is actually working for you, the problem is that you ha too much recors in the DB, and you have to split your data into chunks, take a look at the [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects) method also.

Comment: okey what about paginate it ?The limitation or chunking i will try this at home in the evening

Comment: Yeah, also `paginate` is ok ;)